# How to change text of label that contains input tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I want change **records per page** text but 
when I change text of label : the `select` tag deleted.
Please advice.

```
  <div id="dynamic-table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
        <label>Search:    
            <input aria-controls="dynamic-table" type="text">
        </label>
  </div>
```

jquery :

```
$('#dynamic-table_filter label').text('جستجو');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the textNode and replace it with new text. Using **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** get all children including text and comment node, since textNode is the first child node it can be get by **[`eq(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** then replace content using **[`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**.

```js
$('#dynamic-table_filter label').contents().eq(0).replaceWith('جستجو');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic-table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
  <label>Search:
    <input aria-controls="dynamic-table" type="text">
  </label>
</div>
```

---

Using pure javascript

```js
document.querySelector('#dynamic-table_filter label').firstChild.nodeValue = 'جستجو';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic-table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
  <label>Search:
    <input aria-controls="dynamic-table" type="text">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @programmer138200 : glad to help :)